# Why is this Mysql statement slow AND using wrong indices

Tags: mysql, indexing, mysql-5.7

the SQL at the bottom is super slow ~12-15 seconds. And I don't understand why. Before you read the whole one, just check the first Coalesce part of the first Coalesce. If I replace it with "0", then it is super fast (0.0051s). If I only query the contained Subquery with set-in "client_id", it is super fast, too.

The table "rest_io_log" which is used in the Coalesce contains a lot of entries (more than 5 Million) and therefore got lots of indices to check the contents fast.

The two most important indices for this topic are these:
timestamp - contains only this column
account_id, client_id, timestamp - contains these 3 columns in this order

When I prepend this statement with an "EXPLAIN" it says:

| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | PRIMARY | cl | NULL | range | PRIMARY, index_user_id | index_user_id | 485 | NULL | 2 | 100.00 | Using index condition |
| 1 | PRIMARY | rates | NULL | eq_ref | PRIMARY | PRIMARY | 4 | oauth2.cl.rate | 1 | 100.00 | NULL |
| 4 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | traffic | NULL | ref | unique, unique_account_id_client_id_date, index_date, index_account_id_warning_100_client_id_date | unique | 162 | const, const, oauth2.cl.client_id | 1 | 100.00 | Using index condition |
| 3 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | traffic | NULL | ref | unique, unique_account_id_client_id_date, index_account_id_warning_100_client_id_date | unique_account_id_client_id_date | 158 | const, oauth2.cl.client_id | 56 | 100.00 | Using where; Using index; Using filesort |
| 2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | rest_io_log | NULL | index | index_client_id, index_account_id_client_id_timestamp, index_account_id_timestamp, index_account_id_duration_timestamp, index_account_id_statuscode, index_account_id_client_id_statuscode, index_account_id_rest_path, index_account_id_client_id_rest_path | timestamp | 5 | NULL | 2 | 5.00 | Using where |

on the bottem line we can see there are tons of indices available and it chooses "timestamp" which is actually not the best choice because account_id and client_id is available, too.

If I enforce the right index by adding "USE INDEX (index_account_id_client_id_timestamp)" to the subquery the execution time is reduced to 8 seconds and the EXPLAIN looks like this:

| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | PRIMARY | cl | NULL | range | PRIMARY, index_user_id | index_user_id | 485 | NULL | 2 | 100.00 | Using index condition |
| 1 | PRIMARY | rates | NULL | eq_ref | PRIMARY | PRIMARY | 4 | oauth2.cl.rate | 1 | 100.00 | NULL |
| 4 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | traffic | NULL | ref | unique, unique_account_id_client_id_date, index_date... | unique | 162 | const, const, oauth2.cl.client_id | 1 | 100.00 | Using index condition |
| 3 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | traffic | NULL | ref | unique, unique_account_id_client_id_date, index_acco... | unique_account_id_client_id_date | 158 | const, oauth2.cl.client_id | 56 | 100.00 | Using where; Using index; Using filesort |
| 2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | rest_io_log | NULL | ref | index_account_id_client_id_timestamp | index_account_id_client_id_timestamp | 157 | const, oauth2.cl.client_id | 1972 | 100.00 | Using where; Using index; Using filesort |

```
SELECT
    cl.timestamp AS active_since,
    GREATEST
    (
        COALESCE
        (
            (
                SELECT
                    timestamp AS last_request
                FROM
                    rest_io_log USE INDEX (index_account_id_client_id_timestamp)
                WHERE
                    account_id = 12345 AND
                    client_id = cl.client_id
                ORDER BY
                    timestamp DESC
                LIMIT
                    1
            ),
            "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
        ),
        COALESCE
        (
            (
                SELECT
                    CONCAT(date, " 00:00:00") AS last_request
                FROM
                    traffic
                WHERE
                    account_id = 12345 AND
                    client_id = cl.client_id
                ORDER BY
                    date DESC
                LIMIT
                    1
            ),
            "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
        )
    ) AS last_request,
    (
        SELECT
            requests
        FROM
            traffic
        WHERE
            account_id = 12345 AND
            client_id = cl.client_id AND
            date=NOW()
    ) AS traffic_today,
    cl.client_id AS user_account_name,
    t.rate_name,
    t.rate_traffic,
    t.rate_price
FROM
    clients AS cl
        LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT
                id AS rate_id,
                name AS rate_name,
                daily_max_traffic AS rate_traffic,
                price AS rate_price
            FROM
                rates
        ) AS t
        ON cl.rate=t.rate_id
WHERE
    cl.user_id LIKE "12345|%"
  AND
    cl.client_id LIKE "api_%"
  AND
    cl.client_id LIKE "%_12345"
;
```

the response of the total query looks like this:

| active_since | last_request | traffic_today | user_account_name | rate_name | rate_traffic | rate_price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2019-01-16 15:40:34 | 2019-04-23 00:00:00 | NULL | api_some_account_12345 | Some rate name | 1000 | 0.00 |
| 2019-01-16 15:40:34 | 2022-10-27 00:00:00 | NULL | api_some_other_account_12345 | Some rate name | 1000 | 0.00 |

Can you help?

Comment: Are you saying the 8 second query does what you want but you want to avoid using the index hint?  Or is even it not optimal?

Comment: Just to test: Try with `MAX()` instead of `LIMIT 1`.

Comment: @ysth if main query and subquery both take a lot less than a second why does the combination take up 8 seconds. This one needs to be sped up, becuase it blocks a page load, and then 8 seconds is still too long. I guess I have to query twice then, but I wonder if it could work fast within one SQL, I guess it should...

Comment: @PaulSpiegel Yes it is faster now, today that SQL took 24 seconds after I replaced it with MAX instead of LIMIT 1 it took only 5 Seconds, EXPLAIN said it uses correct indices and "using filesort" is gone now. But why it still takes 5 Seconds...

Comment: 5 Seconds really is a lot it signals that there is a whole lot of data worked on. If it would work as I hoped it would work, it could completely depend on Indices and filter by them.

Comment: I don't know. I've seen MySQL choosing a non optimal index many times. But this here is weird, since you have a perfect covering index. [`ANALYZE TABLE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/analyze-table.html) might help.

Comment: Another issue with your query could be the LEFT JOIN with a subquery (derived table), which is not necessary here. MySQL might optimize it away or it might materialize it to an indexed temp table. But in worst case you would have a join with an unindexed temp table.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel ANALYZE TABLE said the table is OK, I changed the LEFT JOIN to a JOIN without subselect but it didn't change the outcome. I guess some problems shouldn't be solved. I solved this now by using two independant queries

Answer (score 1):

> Why is this Mysql statement slow

- Fetching the same row multiple times.  Use a JOIN instead of repeated subqueries.
- Use MAX instead of ORDER BY and LIMIT 1:

  ```
    SELECT MAX(timestamp)
        FROM ...
        WHERE a=12345 AND c=...
  ```
- Don't use `USE INDEX` -- what helps today may hurt tomorrow.
- Do you really need to fetch both `date` and `timestamp`??  Don't they mean the same thing?  Or does the data entry need to simplify those down to a single column?
- `CONCAT(date, " 00:00:00")` is identical to `date`.  Making that change, let's you combine those first two subqueries.
- `cl.client_id LIKE "api_%" AND  cl.client_id LIKE "%_12345"` ==> `cl.client_id LIKE 'api%12345'`.
- Doesn't use `LEFT JOIN ( SELECT ... ) ON ...`  Instead, simply do `LEFT JOIN rates ON ...`

Suggested indexes:

```
rest_io_log: INDEX(account_id, client_id, timestamp)
clients:  INDEX(user_id, client_id, rate,  timestamp)
rates:  INDEX(rate_id,  rate_name, rate_traffic, rate_price) -- assuming the above change
```